# Expected Value of AR(1) Process

Tags: time-series, stationary-processes

The first order autoregressive process is defined in my textbook to be $ε_t=\phi a_{t-1}+a_t$. Assuming the model is stationary I want to find the expected value of $ε_t$.

If I understand correctly, if a model is stationary then the expected value equals $0$ but I am not sure how to show that it equals zero.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated as I am a bit lost.

Comment: Hint: By the definition of weak stationarity, you have that $E[a_t] = E[a_{t+s}]$ for any $s\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Did my hint above help you?